# Detect when a button is pressed and held by left Mouse

Tags: c#

Trying to have a button perform multiple functions. When the button is just click and released using the left mouse it will send a command to an exe then wait for a short time and send the opposite command. I also need the button to send one command when the button is clicked and the left mouse is held then the opposite when the left mouse is released.

Attached is my code thus far, if I change EventArgs to MouseEventArgs I get a "No overload for 'PowerButton_Click' matches delegate 'EventHandler'"

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
    // Toggle Power Button relay
    private void PowerButton_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //If left mouse held when power button clicked then hold relay on

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Process controlusb = new Process();
            controlusb.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\CommandApp.exe");
            controlusb.StartInfo.Arguments = "afEd5 open 01";
            controlusb.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            controlusb.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
            controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            controlusb.Start();
        }
        //else button no longer held then close the relay and handle the button being clicked and released.
        else
        {
            Process controlusb = new Process();
            controlusb.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\CommandApp.exe");
            controlusb.StartInfo.Arguments = "afEd5 close 01";
            controlusb.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            controlusb.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
            controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            controlusb.Start();

            controlusb.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\CommandApp.exe");
            controlusb.StartInfo.Arguments = "afEd5 open 01";
            controlusb.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            controlusb.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
            controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            controlusb.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            controlusb.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\CommandApp.exe");
            controlusb.StartInfo.Arguments = "afEd5 close 01";
            controlusb.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            controlusb.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
            controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            controlusb.Start();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think you need `PowerButton_MouseUp` event

Comment: `wpf`, `win forms`, `uwp`?

Comment: @Jessey - Don't use click use the `MouseUp` and/or `MouseDown` events as Mike mentions. You can use `MouseUp` in place of the normal click and use `MouseDown` for the held event.

Comment: Set up and start a Timer in the MouseDown. Stop it in the MouseUp and the Tick events.